# Remove a script from the index.html file depending on the path in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on a Vue project, and I have a problem, it is that in the index.html file I have added a script that adds a chat to the page.
I just want the chat to appear in some paths ('/', '/ profile' ...)

I've tried putting an if (window.location.pathname === '/') {.... and it doesn't work as it only works if the page is reloaded, but it doesn't work dynamically.

How could I do it?

Comment: Are you using the Vue Router?

Comment: @mpm if i am using vue router